Why fields are reset within my controller?
I'm experiencing a really weird thing.
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @EventListener
    void onApplicationEvent(final ReactiveWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
        webServerPort = event.getWebServer().getPort();
        log.debug("webServerPort: {}", webServerPort); // 8080 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }


    @Getter
    private int webServerPort;
}

@Validated // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
@RestController
class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    Mono<Void> readStates(final ServerHttpResponse response) {
        log.debug("webServerPort: {}", getWebServerPort()); // 0 <<<<<<<<<<<<

        ....
    }    
}

In the onApplicationEvent method, the webServerPort set with 8080 yet it's 0 on the readStates method.
How come this happen?
I search all places that write the webServerPort field and the onApplicationEvent method is the only one.

I doubt that this is the actual code being used, this wouldn't even compile (missing accessor method).

I am wondering how can you make MyController as a Controller bean. May you miss the @RestController annotation on the MyController class? And is webServerPort() method getter to access parent's webServerPort field?  Could you give us more details or precise code with the context?

Wow the @Validated annotation does something weird thing!

It isn't weird due to where you placed it it needs to proxy things. As your methods aren't public the proxy cannot properly extend the class and the methods will be invoked on the proxy and not passed on to the regular instance (which has the fields). Make the methods public and it will work.

As @M.Deinum commented, the problem was the scope of the method.
It seems following cases work.
public abstract class _ApiController {

    @EventListener // a little-bit narrower(protected) scope!
    protected void onApplicationEvent(final ReactiveWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
        webServer = event.getWebServer();
    }
}

public abstract class _ApiController
        implements ApplicationListener<ReactiveWebServerInitializedEvent> {

    @Override // can't help but to be public 
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ReactiveWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
        webServer = event.getWebServer();
    }
}

